# Adding Simple Content to Dynamic Cell Range VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to programming and even newer to VBA.

I am attempting to add a column to the beginning of a spreadsheet with "retailer" in "A1" and "RetailerName" in "A2:*Last_Relevant_Cell_In_A*".

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub AddRetailerName()

Dim WS_Target As Worksheet
Dim WS_Target_Lastrow As Long

Set WS_Target = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Find last row of WS_Target
WS_Target_Lastrow = WS_Target.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , _
xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

'find last column of WS_Target
WS_Target_Lastcol = WS_Target.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , _
xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Retailer"
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(WS_Target_Lastcol, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "RetailerName"


End Sub
```

This is only inserting content into "A1:A6".  The information inserted is correct, but it should be inserting dynamically with how many rows are found in the spreadsheet (in this example, 950).

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Note: While this operation is simple to complete with a few clicks (without VBA), I plan to use it on around 20 spreadsheets at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(WS_Target_Lastcol, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "RetailerName"
```

to

```
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(WS_Target_Lastrow, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "RetailerName"
```

(I assume your last used cell was in column F?  That would explain your code populating to row 6.)

---

It is also a good idea to qualify your `Range` and `Cells` (etc) methods with the worksheet that they refer to, so I recommend changing your code to:

```
Sub AddRetailerName()

    Dim WS_Target As Worksheet
    Dim WS_Target_Lastrow As Long
    Dim WS_Target_Lastcol As Long

    Set WS_Target = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With WS_Target  ' allows us to use "." instead of "WS_Target."
        'Find last row of WS_Target
        WS_Target_Lastrow = .Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , _
                                        xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

        'find last column of WS_Target
        WS_Target_Lastcol = .Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , _
                                        xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

        .Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Insert
        'Use "Value" rather than "FormulaR1C1" to set a value
        '.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Retailer"
        '.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(WS_Target_Lastrow, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "RetailerName"
        .Range("A1").Value = "Retailer"
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(WS_Target_Lastrow, 1)).Value = "RetailerName"
    End With
End Sub
```

---

And just FYI

```
.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(WS_Target_Lastrow, 1)).Value = "RetailerName"
```

could also be written as either

```
.Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(WS_Target_Lastrow, "A")).Value = "RetailerName"
```

or

```
.Range("A2:A" & WS_Target_Lastrow).Value = "RetailerName"
```

They each achieve the same thing, but different people prefer different styles of coding.

Comment: Thank you for going through this with me.  Your version of the code nearly worked.  I originally got a compiler error.  It worked after I added '.Cells' before '.Find' in the 'WS_Target_Lastcol = .Find("*", [A1], , , )'...line of code.  Either way, this was a tremendous help!  I also appreciate you laying out the different versions of the code that work the same way.  After a little experimenting, I've found I prefer the latter.  Probably because it feels more concise, but that is just me.  Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnSmith - Oops - how embarrassing!! I have edited the answer so no-one else notices my mistake.

Comment: @ YowE3K Lol.  No worries!  It made me think and prove to myself that I knew what was going on in the code.  Thanks again!